# EJB inheritance strategy

Tags: jpa, ejb

**BIG UPDATE:**

Ok, I see my problem is much more complicated than I thought. I have tables like this:

```
Patient:
id
bloodtype
level (FK to level table)
doctor (FK to doctor table)
person (FK to person table)

Doctor:
id
person (FK)
speciality
level (FK to level)

Paramedic:
id
person (FK)

Person:
id
name
surname

Account:
id
login
pass

Level:
id
account (FK)
name (one of: 'patient' , 'paramedic' , 'doctor')
```

In entity class I'm using now `@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,name="name")` in class *Level*. To check if someone is for ex. patient I have function:

```
public boolean ifPatient(String login) {
    account = accountfacade.getByLogin(login);
    for (Level l : account.getLevelCollection()) {
        if (l instanceof Patient) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now I have situation: I'm logged in as a doctor. I want to add a patient. I have something like this:

```
public Doctor findDoctor(String login) {
        account = accountfacade.getByLogin(login);
        for (Doctor d : doctorfacade.findAll()) {
            if (d.getLevel().getAccount().getLogin().equals(login)) {
                doctor = d;
                return doctor;
            }
        }
    }
@Override
    public void addPatient(Account acc, Patient pat, Person per, String login) {
    Doctor d = findDoctor(login);
    accountfacade.create(acc);
    personfacade.create(per);
    Patient p = new Patient();
    p.setAccount(acc);
    p.setBlood(pat.getBlood());
// etc
    p.setPerson(per);
    d.getPatientCollection().add(p);
    acc.getLevelCollection().add(p);
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Always totally weird errors like duplicate value of primary key in table Account (but I use `TableGenerator`...) or NULL value in field Account but for INSERT INTO Doctor (how?! I'm creating new Patient, NOT Doctor...). I'm totally lost now, so I think most important for me now is to know if actually I can use `InheritanceType.JOINED` in this case.

Comment: 1) Do not change the question completely after receiving answers, create a new question. 2) Stop thinking about tables, think about entities. 3) Once 2 is done, the inheritance strategy is not relevant to the operations (it may be interesting to chose one or another depending of performance/size of tables/number of tables, but apart from that all they work the same when you are using the entities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've done what I wanted. It's not elegant, but efficient. Tables and inheritance strategy are the same. In endpoint I create account and person entities, then I create *Patient* entity but using EntityManager *persist()* method. I also need to set id of level manually `((Integer)poziomfacade.getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT max(p.idpoziom) FROM PoziomDostepu p").getSingleResult())+1` because Generator in *Level* entity class doesn't work. Nevertheless the problem is solved, thanks for every constructive comment or answer.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

You are using the field `nazwa` as discriminator

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,name="nazwa")
```

The framework stores there the name of the class that it has to use to deserialize the object (it is the name of the `PoziomDostepu` class).

As far as I can see you are using a different table for each class, so the `Strategy.JOINED` would make little sense.

More update:

Where I said `class` it meant `entity`. You can check the effect by changing the entity name (say to "CacaCuloPedoPis") of `PoziomDostepu` and seeing which is the new value being inserted.

Comment: I accidentally posted before I finished writing whole post. Yes, ids are generated, I don't have to set it by myself. But the most important problem is that field _nazwa_ is set by me and then it changes it's value to 'PoziomDostepu'. I don't know what is going on.

Comment: You are right. When I changed entity name the value of field _nazwa_ also changed. Is there different strategy of inheritance you suggest me, plz?

Comment: You are already using `TABLE_PER_CLASS`. It is just a matter of setting the annotations right. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all that is missing is a @DiscriminatorValue annotation on the PoziomDostepu class to use one of the values in your constraint, otherwise it defaults to the class name.  The insert of PoziomDostepu is coming from the this.poziom - if you don't want PoziomDostepu instances inserted you might make the class abstract and make sure this instance is a subclass instead.   You shouldn't need to change the inheritance type, as doing so will require changing the database tables to each contain the same fields.